# Audit trail using Service Broker

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

Looking for pointers to create audit trial for a database that uses service broker. I have seen many examples online on creating one audit table for all the tables being audited. But what I am looking for is one audit table per base table and the use of service broker to accomplish this. Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: I can think of no circumstance where it is a good idea to have only one audit table for a whole database. Glad you aren't falling for that trap. Why di you want to use Service broker and not triggers?

Comment: @HLGEM - Thanks for your response. Because we want to handle it asynchoronously.

Comment: Can triggers in itself handle requests asynchronously without the help of SB?

Comment: Triggers are part of each transaction. So each transaction would happen asynchonously (you inserting a 1:13 and me inserting at 1:13:01 woudl be porcessed separately by the trigger, but a transaction with a million records inserted would all happen once to the trigger.

Comment: @HLGEM - Thats the problem. A transaction with million records needs to be handled asynchronously. After all it is for the audit trails and it is not needed immediately when the transction completes in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like strange idea.. but what you can try:

- create service broker services and queues (sender and receiver)
- create triggers for all tables that sends from sender to receiver service rows from inserted and deleted tables in trigger- can use "For XML" clause. to automate trigger creation can use procedure sp_msForEachTable.
- make activation procedure for receiver service, that does something with those xml messages

thats about it. you could make better performance by using dialog pool ([here](http://msftsbprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2008!Readme_DialogPool))